# What's "watermark" in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

I'm looking at doing some queries in VSTS.  I see a "watermark" field.  It looks like it's some kind of ID, but I can't figure out what it means.  Does anyone know?

Comment: It isn't the ID, the value will be changed (Increment) when work item be changed.

Comment: Is it like a revision number then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it likes a revision number. The difference is that, the revision increase in work item level while the watermark increase in collection level.

For example, you have two workitems:

> WorkitemA rev:1 watermark: 1
>
> WorkitemB rev:1 watermark: 2

When you update WorkitemA and save it, you will get:

> WorkitemA rev:2 watermark: 3
>
> WorkitemB rev:1 watermark: 2